# randomly select two position in a file and swap words

Tags: python-3.x, list, file, random

I want to select n pairs of word positions (unique) in a file and swap them. My code is as following, but it never gives me n pairs I am looking for.

My logic is first to sample 2*n elements and create n pairs. Then iterate over the file contents (stored in list) and locate the correct positions and make the swap. It is not working. I have difficulty in understanding where it fails.

```
with open(rname) as rd:
    lines = rd.readlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] = lines[i].strip()
sz = sum(len(x.split()) for x in lines)
chosen = random.sample(range(sz),6000)
result = pairwise(chosen)
for (a,b) in result:
    flag1 = 0
    flag2 = 0
    l = 0
    ind1 = 0
    m = 0
    ind2 = 0
    j = 0
    for y in range(len(lines)):
        if ( (j+len(lines[y].split()) >= a) and (flag1 == 0)):
            l = y
            ind1 = a - j-1
            flag1 = 1
        if ( (j+len(lines[y].split()) >= b) and (flag2 == 0)):
            m = y
            ind2 = b - j-1
            flag2 = 1
        if ( (flag1 == 1) and (flag2 == 1)):
                words1 = lines[l].split()
                words2 = lines[m].split()
                words1[ind1], words2[ind2] = 'swapped'+words2[ind2], 'swapped'+words1[ind1]
                lines[l] = ' '.join(words1)
                lines[m] = ' '.join(words2)
                break
        j += len(lines[y].split())
name ='n_file.txt'
with open(wname,'w') as wd:
    for line in lines:
        print(line, file=wd)

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

For example, consider a file with content

`i am here, where are you
it is none of your business`

Let us say i choose 2 positions (2,8) (position is defined in terms of the word positions in the file and start with 0 for the first word in the file). My output will look like

`i am swappednone where are you
it is swappedhere, of your business`

Comment: Please post an example of file contents and what the correct output might look like.

Comment: @alaniwi Included an example.

Comment: So in your example, you want to leave the punctuation in place when swapping words.

Comment: @alaniwi. it was a typo.  sorry. corrected it. words are defined by spaces only.

Comment: Your code would be cleaner if you abstracted the main part into its own function. One which, given a list and an integer `n`, swaps `n` randomly chosen pairs in that list. This is the core of the problem, and shouldn't be cluttered with code which does things like read from files and split strings.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, but this might give you some ideas:

```
import random

def swap_pairs(items,n):
    """swaps n distinct pairs of objects in items"""
    k = len(items)
    indices = random.sample(range(k),2*n)
    random.shuffle(indices)
    for i in range(n):
       s, t = indices[2*i], indices[2*i+1]
       items[s], items[t] = items[t], items[s]
```

This mutates the list in place.

For example, if

```
words = ['i', 'am', 'here,', 'where', 'are', 'you', 'it', 'is', 'none', 'of', 'your', 'business']
```

then after

```
swap_pairs(words,3)
```

words might be

```
['you', 'am', 'it', 'none', 'are', 'i', 'here,', 'is', 'where', 'of', 'your', 'business']
```